# facebook graph api me/likes is returning unpredictable results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Can someone please, please, for the life of me tell me why:

If I visit and "like" the page:
http://www.smashbox.com/product/6036/17776/index.tmpl

If I visit and "like" the page: 
http://sephora.com/browse/product.jhtml?id=P298819

THEN, if I check my "likes" via the graph API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ then clicking the link next to the bullet called "Likes") in the results....ONLY the smashbox.com like is there, but sephora.com is MISSING!!!

Please someone tell me why sephora.com LIKES do NOT appear in the graph api response when they SHOULD. Is it a meta og:tag issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). It will tell you the following for sephora.com:

**Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed**

Inferred Property:  og:type missing. og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.
Inferred Property:  og:image missing. og:image meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

**Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed**

Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

If you fix those issues it might solve your problem. Also check your other url, it has too some errors associated with the open graph.

Comment: I was playing with debugger before as well. It apparently does not make a difference. If you "like" a URL (even with zero meta tags or og:tags)... that like will still appear on the response of "me/likes" on the open graph. any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you already succeeded getting rid of the warnings in the debugger without completely removing the og metatags? Working with the Facebook API is always like trial and lots of error brute force coding on a black box with many surprises inside it. I'm still quite sure that it's not about meta tags or no meta tags but about errors and warnings in the debugger or not. Try to implement the meta tags properly and give me an update please : ]

Comment: It's not clear whether the suggested fixes to the OG warnings resolved the issue.  I actually just lint'd the sephora URL and it still has the same issues, so I'm guessing the changes weren't made.

And I'm actually having this same issue, except that virtually any URL that I like isn't showing up in my /me/likes/ - I've tried ticketmaster, sephora, and my own.